# what is the best way to loop over a large dataset in python?

Tags: python, loops, generator, processing-efficiency

I am currently using the below code to loop over a data set of around 20K records. I created a generator and used it in the for loop. This took around 10 minutes to complete. Is there a more efficient way to loop over large datasets in python? What I am essentially trying to achieve is to identify if there are duplicate values in certain columns for each unique value in the 'number' column of the dataframe(df_ir) and if there is, then storing the total number of duplicates for each column in the dictionary d_cnt.

df_ir is a pandas dataframe with 120k records
df_ir['number'].unique() = 20K records

```
lst_tk = ['caller_id','opened_by','made_sla']
d_cnt = {}
for col in lst_tk:
      d_cnt[col]=0

gen_inc = (i for i in df_ir['number'].unique())

for incnum in gen_inc:
    for col in lst_tk:
        if df_ir[df_ir['number']== incnum][col].value_counts().count()>1:
            d_cnt[col]+=1
```

Comment: Can u add the sample input & expected output.

Comment: What is a "dataset"? Are you working with a pandas dataframe? Then the most efficient way is to use itertuples, but you should avoid any sort of explicit looping over a dataframe to begin with

Comment: as for me your generator is useless - you should get the same speed with `for incnum in df_ir['number'].unique()`

Comment: Your best bet is to throw your logic into a separate function, then apply it over the whole dataframe with one apply pass.

Comment: Thanks to all for your helpful insights. I have for now with my limited knowledge used a slightly modified version of Jared Wilber's option (used pandas filter and then stored the results in a new dataframe instead of using a dictionary) to achieve my objective and the code seems to running much faster now. Thanks all!!!

Comment: @abds20 - if you're using pandas, there's probably a vectorized way of achieving what you're trying to do. I'll run in seconds if not less. If you provide sample input and output, someone would be able to suggest a way of doing that.